# Rails - How to set regex as method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a regex that I want to use for word count and validation. However, I don't want to have to go into every model and controller if I decide to change the regex I'm using. Is there a way to create a helper method that defines the regex?

This is what I've tried and it doesn't work:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def word_count(content_text)
    content_text.scan(scan_regex).size
  end

  def scan_regex
    return "/\b(([a-zA-Z’'-]))+((?![^<>]*>)+(?![^&;]*;))\b/"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove the '/' from the regexp and then add them to scan:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def word_count(content_text)
    content_text.scan(/#{scan_regex}/).size
  end

  def scan_regex
    return "\b(([a-zA-Z’'-]))+((?![^<>]*>)+(?![^&;]*;))\b"
  end

end
```

Comment: Great! Also needed to take out the \b and it worked!